# Stratified Sampling in R with a slightly unbalanced sample?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to pull out a subset of some data so I can try out reliability coding for a research project. I am having some trouble pulling out a stratified sample from this data set.

Here is the code I wrote. What I wanted this code to do was pull out 80 observations out of the total of 240 observations. There are a total of 8 conditions (called df$sessions) in the dataset, and I wanted to pull out 10 examples from each condition--this part of the code worked. There are also 30 participants, so I worked it out that each participant should be represented 2 or 3 times--this part of the code did not work, as in the final_sample dataframe, some participants had 1 example, and others had up to 5.

```
set.seed(123)

# Specify the sample size
total_sample_size <- 80

# Specify the desired number of observations per session
observations_per_session <- 10

# Specify the range of observations per participant
min_observations_per_participant <- 2
max_observations_per_participant <- 3

# Create an empty data frame to store the sampled data
sampled_data <- data.frame()

# Create a function to sample within the specified constraints
sample_function <- function(df_group) {
  sample_size_session <- min(observations_per_session, nrow(df_group))
  
  # Calculate the minimum number of observations required for each participant
  min_participant_samples <- table(df_group$participant)
  min_participant_samples[which.min(min_participant_samples)] <- min_observations_per_participant
  max_participant_samples <- pmin(table(df_group$participant), max_observations_per_participant)
  
  df_group %>%
    group_by(participant) %>%
    sample_n(size = max_participant_samples[1], replace = TRUE) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    sample_n(size = sample_size_session) %>%
    ungroup()
}

# Apply the sampling function per session
sampled_data <- df %>%
  group_by(session) %>%
  group_split() %>%
  map_df(~ sample_function(.))

# Take a random sample of the overall dataset to achieve the desired sample size
final_sample <- sampled_data %>%
  slice_sample(n = total_sample_size)

# Print the result
print(final_sample)

# Test that no participant or session is over/under-sampled
table(final_sample$participant)
table(final_sample$session)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO jqmr. 1) Do you mean your data has 240 observations *in total*, or that there are 240 observations *per participant*? 2) If there is only 240 observations *in total*, does that mean each participant has a equal number of observations (n = 8)? 3) What is the distribution of conditions relative to each participant? Need to know more about your data to help find a solution. Thanks.